# Extract only variables and coefficients with Signif. less 0.05 in R

Tags: r, regression

I did a ridge regression (function linearRidge, package ridge) in R , this regression had 55 coefficients. How can I extract only variables and coefficients that have a Pr (> | t |) less than 0.05. I have reviewed and in an lm model this can be done as follows:

```
fit <- lm( formula, data=yourData)
coeffs <- summary(fit)$coefficients
coeffs[coeffs[4,] < 0.05,]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `broom` would make it easier:

```
library(tidyverse)
fit <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + drat + wt + qsec + vs + am,
  data = mtcars
)
coef <- broom::tidy(fit)
coef %>% filter(p.value < 0.05)

# or

subset(coef, coef$p.value < 0.05)
```

Comment: I get this error: Error: No tidy method for objects of class ridgeLinear. 

I did a ridge regression (function linearRidge, package ridge).

Comment: I see. Obviously you didn’t use `lm` as shown in your OP. I you provide your code with a reproducible example, it would be easier to work out a solution

Comment: The data is https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/482081/data-with-multicollinearity-and-p-n